# What does having an inertia tensor of zero do in Bullet?

Tags: physics, bulletphysics, bullet

In the Bullet Physics library, when constructing a rigid body the default argument for the inertia tensor is the zero vector.

My understanding of inertia is fairly elementary but from the equation

torque = inertia * angular_velocity

I would expect angular velocity on an object with zero inertia to be undefined.

The [documentation for constructing rigid bodies](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtRigidBody_1_1btRigidBodyConstructionInfo.html) says

> For dynamic objects, you can use the collision shape to approximate
>   the local inertia tensor, otherwise use the zero vector (default
>   argument)

So what happens with this zero inertia? Have I misunderstood the equation? Or is having zero inertia in Bullet similar to having zero mass in defining an object to be static with respect to orientation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start let us define inertia.

> Inertia is the resistance of any physical object to a change its state of motion, or the tendency of an object to resist any change in its motion.

The off diagonal elements of the *Inertia Tensor* are called the products of inertia. The products of inertia are zero when the body is symmetrical about the axes of rotation, such as for a rectangular box or cylinder rotating on their symmetry axis. I would imagine that the *Inertia Tensor* that is used in the physics engine you use is *always* diagonal to avoid complexity.

I suppose in the case of your ballistic physic engine, where this torque might come in to play is for an object that let's say is spinning around the z-axis with the following angular velocity (0, 0, ωr) [in cylindrical coordinates (r, theta, z)], then you might want to find out the torque required to stop this rotation in some time t (i.e. a rotational acceleration of magnitude -ωr/t). Here you would then use the equation you have stated above.

The interpretation of the zero matrix would be to represent zero 'inertia', and object with no mass and what I have said above again holds.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for clarifying. As I understand the inertia tensor is a 3x3 matrix which makes the equation make sense. In Bullet you provide a 3 component vector for inertia from which I assume the 3x3 matrix is derived.

Comment: There is a bit more explanation here (not got the time to read fully myself at the moment): http://techhouse.brown.edu/~dmorris/projects/tutorials/inertia.tensor.summary.pdf

Comment: I also came across this link. And to be clear, with the inertia tensor is referred to the moment of inertia, which affects angular acceleration (not velocity) so: torque = moment_of_inertia * angular_acceleration.
And I think they initiate a zero vector in case the object is a point mass, in which case you can't apply a torque on it.

Comment: No, the inertia tensor is _made up of_ individual moments of inertia.

Answer (score -4):

By building a zero inertia bubble or a negative state of flux, a bullet's dynamic will be nominal to tensor point and underlying rotation, regardless of torque, vector or angle. To simply state otherwise is dense or incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nominal'? Also the question is not regarding the dynamics of a bullet necessarily, but the physics engine named 'Bullet'.

Comment: What has an object with zero inertia got to do with 'flux'. You answer is non-sense.